# Controlling animation from code behind in WPF button?

Tags: wpf, animation, button, code-behind

I have the following XAML style for my button :

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="BtnBorder" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" CornerRadius="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=BtnBorder, Path=ActualWidth}">        
                        <Rectangle Name="BtnRect" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="5" Opacity="0.2" Fill="White" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="progressIndicator" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Margin="1">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#88FFFFFF" Offset="0.945" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="BtnCP" />
                      </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BtnRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.25" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BtnRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.5" To="0.25" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BtnBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.3" />
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="progressIndicator" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="300" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="5x" />
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BtnBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5,0,1.5,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="BtnBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.3" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can i control the animation of the Rectangle property of my button through code behind upon clicking the button.
The Rectangle named "progressIndicator" is to grow in width through animation when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 0):

Currently animation starts in Xaml. Why do you want to it in code-behind?

Comment: Actually I want a background process to decide the duration of animation on the button. So the animation, starts when the user clicks on the button and after certain validation and it ends when the background process is finished.